# Anonymous users prompted to sign in to add a comment to blog post

Tags: blog, anonymous-authentication

We want to add a blog to our website and need to allow anonymous users to post comments. I have obviously shared to anonymous users and gave them the post, edit, view, delete permissions. Our server is up to date with the most recent hotfix patches. They are still prompt to sign in though.

Build:
On prem SP site.

Comment: Bumping for visibility.

Comment: Can they read/reach the blog anonymously (ie: is it only prompting when trying to post a comment)?

Answer (score 0):

Is this in SharePoint 2013? Disable the "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" Site Collection Feature when active.

Reference: http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2013/01/26/sharepoint-2013-and-anonymous-users-accessing-lists-and-libraries.aspx

Comment: I just looked and I can confirm that it is disabled. I don't believe it has ever been turned on. Thanks for posting.